Adding two numbers in Tally marks
Given two positive integers, add them.
Both inputs and output are in Tally marks form, which can be expressed as:
$$ T(n) := \begin{cases} n,&& n\le 5\\ 5 || T(n-5),&& n>5 \end{cases} $$
and for n=1 to 15, T(n) are 1,2,3,4,5,51,52,53,54,55,551,552,553,554,555, respectively.
Shortest code win.
Test cases:
1 + 1 = 2
4 + 2 = 51
51 + 5552 = 55553
5 + 5 = 55
52 + 53 = 555

Note

Technically U+1D360-U+1D378                                                    are used, but U+0031-U+0035  1 2 3 4 5  should be more friendly to most languages, and you can get a font to make them display as you want XD


Sandbox

@JonathanAllan No U+0030(0) ever exist in IO

How flexible is the input format? For e.g. 551+552, are we allowed to use a single argument "551552"? Or a pair of lists of digits such as [[5,5,1],[5,5,2]]?

is 550 acceptable output for 55?

@noodleman I assume not, since there is no 0 in the I or the O, according to a previous comment.

Suggest a test case with inputs of different lengths

Retina 0.8.2, 15 bytes
.
$*
1{1,5}
$.&

Try it online! Link is to test suite that splits each test on = and runs the code on both halves although obviously the output for a single tally mark is the same as the input. Explanation:
.
$*

Convert everything to unary. Non-digits are simply deleted.
1{1,5}
$.&

Convert up to 5 1s to decimal at a time.

Jelly, 5 bytes
FSs5Ẉ

A monadic Link that accepts a list of summands as lists of integers from \$[1,5]\$ and yields a single list of integers from \$[1,5]\$.
Try it online! Or see the test-suite.
How?
FSs5Ẉ - Link: list of lists of integers, Summands  e.g.: [[5,2],[5,1]]
F     - flatten the Summands                             [5,2,5,1]
 S    - sum                                              13
  s5  - split into chunks of five (or less at right)     [[1..5],[6..10],[11,12,13]]
    Ẉ - length of each                                   [5,5,3]


A dyadic Link is also possible in five bytes with +Ss5Ẉ TIO / tests

Perl 5 + -F -MList::Util+sum -M5.10.0, 28 bytes
-3 bytes from @Xcali's suggestion!
say 5x(($b=sum@F)/5),$b%5||$
Try it online!

Same logic, one byte shorter: Try it online!

Nice I got -3 from that! Thanks!

Python, 45 43 bytes
-2 bytes thanks to @Jonathan Allan
lambda a,b:(c:=sum(a+b))//5*[5]+[c%5][:c%5]

Attempt This Online!
Takes input as lists of digits (as integers)

Oh, I was so close :p

...[:c%5] from mine saves two bytes.

@JonathanAllan, yeah noticed that as soon I saw your answer

BitCycle, 35 bytes
?+?+
v< <   <
A\\\\\B^
v~v<<<
> C\!

Try it!
Explanation
The -u flag converts lists of numbers to unary, with 0 as a separator. So first, we take the two inputs (?) and use + devices to send the 0 bits off the playfield and send the 1 bits into the collector A. This takes the sum of all the numbers in the input.
Then the 1 bits loop between collectors A and B. Each time through the loop, the splitters \ redirect the first five bits downward. The first one (from the leftmost splitter) goes through the dupneg ~; the negated copy, 0, turns left and gets to the C collector first, followed by the unchanged copy and all the other 1 bits. Thus, C gets the sum, partitioned into groups of five 1 bits, with a 0 before each group.
This can't be output as-is because it has a leading separator 0, which would put a zero in front of the list. So before we output the contents of C, we use one more splitter to get rid of that first bit.

APL+WIN, 29 23 22 bytes
Prompts for a vector of integers and outputs a vector of integers:
(((⌊n÷5)⍴5),5|n←+/⎕)~0

Try it online! Thanks to Dyalog Classic

Vyxal,  6  5 bytes
Note: now the same as Lyxal's Vyncoded answer which also ports my Jelly answer.
ɾf5ẇ@

Try it Online!
How?
Almost a straight port of my Jelly answer, just moving the implicit range that s does in Jelly out to a leading ɾ and using the flattened result.
ɾf5ẇ@                                           e.g. [[5,2],[5,1]]
ɾ     - range (vectorises)                           [[[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2]],[[1,2,3,4,5],[1]]]
 f    - flatten                                      [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,1,2,3,4,5,1]
  5ẇ  - split into chunks of five (or less at right) [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,1,2,3],[4,5,1]]
    @ - length of each                               [5,5,3]


R, 49 46 bytes
\(x,s=Reduce(sum,x))c(rep(5,s/5),if(s%%5)s%%5)

Attempt This Online!
Takes input as a list of vectors of digits. Outputs a vector of digits.

Vyxal, 36 bitsv2, 4.5 bytes
ɾf5ẇ@

Try it Online!
Bitstring:
001000011111011010110101101001110010

Very similar to the Jelly answer, but slightly different in the first half. Takes both tallies in a single list. Tallies are represented as lists of digits.
Explained
ɾf5ẇ@­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
ɾ      # ‎⁡range 1..N for each N in each tally
 f     # ‎⁢flatten that
  5ẇ   # ‎⁣split into chunks of length 5
    @  # ‎⁤and vectorise length


Created with the help of Luminespire.

5 + 5 needs to return 55 not 550.

@JonathanAllan fixed

Oh, I also took the range out to the front to avoid summing and the ɾ effectively needed by ẇ; but I have not Vyncoded :D (EDIT - I still think this should be classed as a different language...)

JavaScript (ES6), 53 bytes
Expects two strings as (a)(b).
a=>b=>(g=x=>x>5?"5"+g(x-5):x)(eval([...a+b].join`+`))

Try it online!

K (ngn/k), 15 bytes
5&(5<)-[;5]\+/,

Try it online!
Input two digit lists as x f y.
            +/, sum
      -[;5]     decrement by 5
  (5<)           while >5
           \     keep intermediate values
5&              >5 becomes 5


nice! are you familiar with null-reshapes like 0N 5#? idea: use & to make a list of zeroes, reshape it with 0N 5#, and count the zeroes in each row with #'

@ngn ah, I thought there was something like that but forgot how to do it. I did want to post an answer with this approach in any case, though.

Wolfram Language (Mathematica), 102 68 bytes
Saved 34 bytes thanks to @Greg Martin

Golfed version. Try it online!
Join[5~Table~#,#2~Table~Sign@#2]&@@Tr@Flatten@#~QuotientRemainder~5&

Ungolfed version. Try it online!
f[x_List] := 
 Module[{s = Total[Flatten[x]], quotient, remainder}, 
  quotient = Quotient[s, 5];
  remainder = Mod[s, 5];
  Flatten[{Table[5, {quotient}], 
    If[remainder != 0, remainder, Nothing]}]]
f[{1, 1}] // Print
f[{4, 2}] // Print
f[{{5, 5, 1}, {5, 5, 2}}] // Print
f[{5, 5}] // Print
f[{{5, 2}, {5, 3}}] // Print


I wonder whether one can find a shorter way to mimic the long-named QuotientRemainder function ... but for general golfy modifications of your method, here's a 68-byte version.

This uses a different approach: Clip[Range[#~Total~2,1,-5]/5]*5&

Google Sheets, 82 80 78 bytes
=LET(s,SUM(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A2&B2,,"9"),9)),l,MOD(s,5),REPT(5,s/5)&IF(l,l,))



sed, 84
s/(.*) (5*)/\2\1/
s/4/22/g
s/3/21/g
s/2/11/g
s/1{5}/5/
s/1{4}/5/
s/1{3}/5/
s/1{2}/5/

Try it online!

s/11/2, s/21/3, s/31/4 saves 6 bytes.

Charcoal, 11 bytes
⭆⪪⭆Ｓ×ψΣι⁵Ｌι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as two tally numbers separated by punctuation. Explanation:
   Ｓ        Input string
  ⭆         Map over characters and join
     ψ      Null byte
    ×       Repeated by
       ι    Current character
      Σ     Extract digit value if any
 ⪪          Split into groups of length
        ⁵   Literal integer `5`
⭆           Map over groups and join
          ι Current group
         Ｌ  Length
            Implicitly print


Retina, 44 bytes
2
11
3
111
4
1111
5
11111
;

1{5}
5
(1)+
$#1

First, converts everything into unary, deletes a semicolon I used as a seperator, replaces groups of five 1s by 5 and converts the remainder back to decimal.
Attempt This Online!

Python 3.8, 47 bytes
lambda*t:(s:=sum(sum(t,[])))//5*[5]+[s%5][:s%5]

An unnamed function that accepts any number of summands each as a list of integers from \$[1,5]\$ and returns a list of integers from \$[1,5]\$.
Try it online!

Google Sheets, 90 bytes
=let(v,sum(split(regexreplace(A1&B1,"(.)","$1 ")," ")),rept(5,v/5)&iferror(1/mod(v,5)^-1))

Put the input in cells A1:B1 and the formula in C1.


Haskell + hgl, 13 bytes
cxS 5<<pl.*sm

Explanation
We sum both lists with pl.*sm. sm<<mp would also work just fine. Then we split the result into chunks of size 5 with cxS 5
Reflection
This is overall quite short. None of the components seem sensible to combine. The single exception here is that cxS should probably have pre-loaded variants for small number inputs. 2 especially is quite useful, but might as well go up to 10 as is usual.  This would save 2 bytes.

Acc!!, 93 89 bytes
-4 bytes thanks to @DLosc
1
Count i while _%6 {
_-_%6+N%6*7
}
_/6-6
Count i while _/5%_ {
Write 53
_-5
}
Write 48+_

Try it online!
Inputs should be separated by a space. Exits with error when output is a multiple of 5.

@DLosc, I did have a working version, but then tab chaos struck and I posted the wrong one!; Fixed now

Ah, makes sense. Here's 89 bytes.

Uiua SBCS, 13 bytes
⊜⧻\+=0◿5.⇡/+⊂

Takes two digit lists and returns a digit list.
Try it!
⊜⧻\+=0◿5.⇡/+⊂­⁡​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
             ⊂  # ‎⁡prepend
           /+   # ‎⁢sum
          ⇡     # ‎⁣range
         .      # ‎⁤duplicate
       ◿5       # ‎⁢⁡modulo five (vectorizing)
     =0         # ‎⁢⁢mask of where this is equal to zero
   \+           # ‎⁢⁣cumulative sum
⊜⧻             # ‎⁢⁤lengths of contiguous equal numbers


Core Maude 3.4, 88 bytes
mod A is gb LIST{Nat}. var A B : NzNat . cq A B =(A + B)if A < 5 . eq s_^5(A)= 5
A . endm

The tallies to add are input as a flat list of digits between 1 and 5, which is reduced in the module. The resulting output is another list of digits.
Example Session
Maude> select A .
Maude> reduce 1 1 .
result NzNat: 2
Maude> reduce 4 2 .
result NeList{Nat}: 5 1
Maude> reduce 5 1 5 5 5 2 .
result NeList{Nat}: 5 5 5 5 3
Maude> reduce 5 5 .
result NeList{Nat}: 5 5
Maude> reduce 5 2 5 3 .
result NeList{Nat}: 5 5 5

Ungolfed
mod A is
    gb LIST{Nat} .

    var A B : NzNat .

    cq A B = (A + B) if A < 5 .
    eq s_^5(A) = 5 A .
endm

For any two adjacent tally marks, if the left is less than 5 then the program will combine them. So 4 5 becomes 9. If any tally mark is greater than 5 then the program will break it apart. So 9 becomes 5 4. Any “unfull” tally marks will percolate down the list until they are combined at the end.
